# Why is anonymous method that has expression of type int having its type inferred as Func<int?>?

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference, anonymous-methods

I have a generic function that is supposed to traverse a sequence of properties within a LINQ expression to compare against another passed-in value but discovered that the LINQ expression contained a convert operation, which my function was not expecting. I've been going over the [C# type inference docs](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/standard-v6/standard/expressions.md#1163-type-inference) to see how this could have happened but haven't been having a lot of luck figuring it out. In the process I ended up simplifying the problem to the following.

The generic function:

```cs
public static void M<T>(Func<T> func, T value)
{
}
```

In this block of code the type of `T` is inferred to be `int?`, which I wasn't expecting and was trying to figure out why.

```cs
int? value = null;
M(() => 5, value);
```

I was comparing it against this next block of code which fails type inference.

```cs
int? value = null;
Func<int> function = () => 5;
M(function, value);
```

I believe I understand why type inference fails here: the return type of the function no longer needs to be inferred and `Func<int>` has no implicit conversion to `Func<int?>` since they are dealing with value types, not reference types.
In the first example it seems to me that type inference sees that the anonymous method's expression type of `int` is implicity convertible to `int?` and then infers the anonymous method's type to be `Func<int?>`.
Is this what is happening or is something else going on here?
If so, I'm kind-of surprised to see type inference reach into the expression and implicitly convert what it was returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically thinking along the right lines, although I wouldn't phrase it quite as you did in the question. Type inference is massively complicated, and just reading through the C# standard I'm *fairly* convinced I've spotted at least one error (`xᵢ` should be `pᵢ` in some places; I'll try to get that fixed next week), so I'll avoid the formal process.

Instead, let's look at the two situations separately:

## Situation 1

```cs
public static void M<T>(Func<T> func, T value) {}
...
int? value = null;
M(() => 5, value);
```

There are two arguments: an anonymous function, and a simple variable of type `int?`.

The inference process will infer:

- There must be an implicit conversion from `5` to `T`, in order for there to be a conversion from the anonymous function to `Func<T>`
- There must be an implicit conversion from `int?` (the type of the `value` variable) to `T`, in order for the second argument to be valid

Massively hand-wavy, but it's reasonable to imagine the compiler saying, "Hey, let's just try `T=int?` here":

- The first condition is met, as there *is* an implicit conversion from `5` to `int?`. So we can convert `() => 5` to a `Func<int?>`
- The second condition is trivially met as there's an identity conversion from `int?` to `int?`

## Situation 2

```cs
public static void M<T>(Func<T> func, T value) {}
...
int? value = null;
Func<int> function = () => 5;
M(function, value);
```

Here, type inference requires:

- There must be an implicit conversion from `Func<int>` to `Func<T>` for the first argument to be valid - which means there must be an *identity* conversion from `int` to `T`
- There must be an implicit conversion from `int?` to `T` for the second argument to be valid

Type inference fails as there's no type `T` that satisfies both of those constraints.

Comment: Okay, that helps clarify some of my confusion regarding type inference of an anonymous method, though I'm still curious regarding some of the details in the hand-waving. When I was trying to work Situation 1 out myself I was never quite sure how the bounds of `T` was calculated, e.g. was the lower-bound set `{ int, int? }` or `{ int? }` after the first phase or even something else entirely? I was having a hard time figuring out type inference for this anonymous method when I was going through the docs.

Comment: @themills22: If it's any consolation to you, everyone else has a hard time with this as well. I wouldn't like to speculate on the lower-bound set without spending a serious amount of time poring over the spec... this is one of the most complex areas of the language.

Comment: No worries, I was crossing my fingers that you could give a quick-ish response but wasn't expecting one due to the problem's complexity. You've given me some new information to consider when I take another detailed look into the type inferencing.